# Async loading two dependent streams when using FutureBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, stream-builder

In a pretty complex sheet, I am using `FutureBuilder` and `Listview.builder` which help me to list all groups around me (using Algolia search), which looks as follows:

```
future = _algolia
              .index('groups')
              .setAroundLatLng(
                  '${_startLocation.latitude.toString()}, ${_startLocation.longitude.toString()}')
              .setFacetFilter("category:$category")
              .search(_query)
              .setHitsPerPage(1000)
              .getObjects();
```

Now, I also want to include the `totalUsers` for each group. Problem: they are saved in Firestore (groups/groupId/totalUsers). Now for Firestore when I need to request the `totalUsers`, I have to hand over every `groupId` (which comes async from Algolia and is simply available in `FutureBuilder` as `document.data['groupId']`). So I tried to call `totalUsers` from a ListTile within `FutureBuilder`, with `getTotalUsers(document.data['groupId']),` and

```
  getTotalUsers(groupId) async{
    DocumentReference reference =
    Firestore.instance.collection('groups').document(groupId.toString());
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot;
    snapshot = await reference.get();
    return snapshot['totalUsers'];
  }
```

...but since it is async, it just gives me 'Instance of a Future'. Now what's the easiest way to include totalUsers and 'await' it from the widget tree? I think I cannot load it in initstate, since I first have to hand over the specific userIds from the groups 'aroundme'.

Comment: Please share how you are trying to use these two methods?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/msw333/0060c5cb00bb3c38f246eeba9b491396 - async infos are loaded in line 81 and 86